# Error Spring get Jacoco coverage End-to-end testing

Tags: spring, gradle, jacoco

I'm trying to get end-to-end test coverage with Jacoco which is based on API hit, not by running unit test. I followed this tutorial:
https://dzone.com/articles/code-coverage-report-generator-for-java-projects-a

However I got this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader 'bootstrap' attempted duplicate class definition for java.lang.$JaCoCo. (java.lang.$JaCoCo is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

I don't know what cause the error:
The project uses gradle and I also apply jacoco plugin for unit test (I need coverage for both unit test and end-to-end test).

But I'm not sure if that cause the `LinkageError` because if I remove all jacoco related things from gradle, the same error still appears.

How to properly setup jacoco coverage for end-to-end testing with gradle? If not possible, is there any alternative?

Comment: Got the same problem. @noname2 have you been able to resolve it?